# Can't add box with vagrant on windows 10

Tags: windows, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm on windows 10, last version of vagrant 1.9.3, and when I try to add a box I keep getting the same message:

```
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
Error: Failed writing body (0 != 11933)
```

I tried different solutions found here and on github, nothing seem to be working out. Installed this "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)", deleted embedded curl from vagrant and installed latest version for windows. Also tried with different terminal. What's next?

Comment: does `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` help ?

Comment: no that's the command I use already and I get the error I copy/pasted above. I should have added this command in my topic, thanks for trying though

Comment: ok then you can try to download the file directly and install the box from the downloaded file

Comment: I couldn't install a local box either. I finally managed to understand the problem was coming from Vagrant that can not handle special characters in my username account on windows 10.

Comment: duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320441/vagrant-on-w7-cant-find-any-box but more obvious because of the accents all over the username here :-)..