# Having issue with Vagrant I cant install any Vagrantbox

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I saw scotch.io vagrant box and i was please with it. so i went ahead to download virtualbox and vagrant. also downloaded the scotch.io vagrantfile. but i when i enter the `vagrant up` in that dir using cmd an pc user.

it gives this error

```
C:\Users\Myusername\Desktop\scotch-box-master>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'scotch/box' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'scotch/box' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/scotch/box"]
Error:
```

so i tried to install precise64 box it tries to download but it give an error back as follow

```
C:\Users\Myusername\Desktop\Vagrant>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'precise64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'precise64' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box
    default: Progress: 100% (Rate: 24/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

please can some help me fix this error.
so i just downloaded the precise64.tar file how can i install it locally since remote installation is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea from the above user said all i have to do was check if my pc name has any special charcter ed -/@#$% etc and then remove the special charater. that all and vagrant is downloading the box very well and correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have used vagrant on windows successfully, and it works well with VirtualBox, but there are pitfalls compared to starting with OSX or Linux..  The best advice I found was here: http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/01/25/how-to-use-vagrant-on-windows.html For instance I needed to learn to start a command window as administrator and work around the symlink issues especially.  I have used scotchbox on a Mac though and it worked perfectly right out of the box, so fiddling first with the known Windows issues first might get you there?

Comment: thanks at @George M for your answer i went ahead to download the Precise64.tar file how do i install it locally where do i drop this file

Comment: If you can't download any box, the problem is with the configuration of VirtualBox, not with the boxes themselves..

Comment: I did not see any solution related to my question

Comment: did you clone the repository, or just download the Vagrantfile?

Comment: when you say vagrant -v, what is the response? did you follow the scotchbox instructions to install it?

Comment: and finally did you check out this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320441/vagrant-on-w7-cant-find-any-box

Comment: 1.95 that is my version

Comment: question is for mac user not pc it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: i'm confused - you're using a mac, or you think the question refers to a mac?  because the question is about win7..  But I could imagine the same could apply to a Mac, if you had a special character anywhere in the path you're trying to install to

Comment: No special character anywhere